# RabbitMQ architecture to manage trips and coordinates

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm new to RabbitMQ, but I know that my use case fits well in this kind of architecture. What I want to achieve is the following.

Using an android application, the user will push the "start trip" button. This will call to an API which will create the trip. Then, the android application will send data periodically, gps coordinates, to the API (which will accomplish some task). When the user finishes the trip, another call to the API will be made.

Until now, the API was a simple Restful written using spring boot. Now, I want to make changes to the architecture and add RabbitMQ.

I've thought that whenever a trip is started, the API will create a Queue (queue_trip_XXX, as XXX is the trip identificator), bound to a exchange (trips_exchange) with a routing key (trip_XXX). Then, but dynamically, gps coordinates will be sent to the exchange and routed to the corresponding queue. When the user ends the trip, the queue will be removed.

So, there will be one queue for each trip and a unique exchange. Is this appropriate? Do you have any other solution that would best fit to this use case?

Another question is how can I create a consumer which listens to messages sent to a queue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to create separate queues for every trip?

In RabbitMQ every queue is a separate Erlang process, so the broker may fail at some point when you'll have more and more active users of your application.

Answer (score 1):

> So, there will be one queue for each trip and a unique exchange. Is this appropriate?

As I've mentioned in the comment I don't think it's a good idea due to the fact that every queue in RabbitMQ is a separate Erlang process.

Is there any reason why you would like to process messages from one trip separately from the others? Maybe one queue will be enough for start?

> Another question is how can I create a consumer which listens to messages sent to a queue?

I assume you already have two nodes (one for API and one for RabbitMQ broker).
You should just create the third one which will be responsible for processing the data.

Comment: I understand that every queue means a new Erlang process. The issue here is that a trip started from the android app will be sending lot of messages to the queue. Additionally, several android applications will be sending messages, and it's likely that simultaneously. Each message will contain a coordinate. Coordinates from a trip must be dealt with ordered and a task will be accomplished per each. First coordinates task will last little time, but that time will become longer (as the process will require more time). That's the reason why I'd like to separate each queue.

Comment: You're worried by order of processing messages, because you assume you'll have several workers, and then if all of them will consume from the same queue, then race-condition may occur?
If so, then you could spawn messages across consumers using [consent hash plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange/README.md), then coordinates from a trip will be stored in the same queue, but there will be also coordinates from other trips as well.

Comment: And here's the second problem.
If I understood correctly you want several first coordinates to be processed fast, but later could wait.
So [priority queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) could help you with that. Setting priority on queues causes a drop in performance, but since you need only 2 levels of priority it should not be a problem.

Comment: Each trip has some sort of cache. Each trip has to be dealth with separately, since coordinates sent by a trip will be processed using a match making algorithm and a LineString will be built. That's the reason, this is, each trip should be processed in a different thread. Also, I thought to use a delayed Direct Exchange.

Comment: So it's getting to be more a design problem than a specific technical question. If you want we may meet on call and think about the solution.